# Export Error in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, time-series

The below code exports monthly data. However while it is saving in Google Drive, returns this error:

```
Error: Expected a homogeneous image collection, but an image with incompatible bands was encountered: First image type: 1 bands ([1993030100]). Current image type: 1 bands ([1993030200]). Image ID: null Some bands might require explicit casts.
```

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a3062bac73d72ca444106081ff99ecca

```
var temporalCollection = function(collection, start, count, interval, units){
  
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(count).subtract(1.0));
  var originDate = ee.Date(start);
  
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i){
    
    var startDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(i), units);
    var endDate = originDate.advance(ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), units);
    
    return collection.filterDate(startDate, endDate).mean().clip(table)
    .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
    .set('system:time_end', endDate.millis());
  }));
};

var sailinity = function(img){
  var nam = img.id();
  var bands = img.select(['salinity_0']).multiply(0.001).add(20.0).clip(table);
  return bands.rename(nam)
  .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
};

var HYCOM = ee.ImageCollection("HYCOM/sea_temp_salinity")
.filterDate('1993-01-01','2003-01-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.map(sailinity);

print(HYCOM);


var HYCOM9303 = temporalCollection(HYCOM, '1993-01-01', 120, 1, 'month').toBands();


print('HYCOM9303',HYCOM9303);


Export.image.toDrive({
  image: HYCOM9303,
  description: 'HYCOM9303',
  scale: 10000,
  region: table,
  crs: HYCOM9303.getInfo().crs,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you got complains that the bandname of image in image collection are not homogeneous. So I remove the band rename command in line 23, it successfully export your image to Drive. Here is the edited code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8a8d3fe4fa98feb94c895707a01adc0e